# Writing function similar to String.format

Tags: java

Is it possible to write similar function as `String.format()`, where first argument is a string with placeholders and other arguments are could be of different types? how this function `format` is organised then in Java?

Comment: `String.format()` uses a [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) internally.

Comment: Are you asking "how does the formatter process the placeholders" or "how can we pass multiple objects"? Or something completely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just do something like

```
public static String myMethod(String str, Object... args) {
    ...
}
```

i.e. we make use of [*varargs*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

---

From the [source of the `String` class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java):

```
2780 public static String format(String format, Object ... args) {
2781     return new Formatter().format(format, args).toString();
2782 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void someFunction(String string, Object... objects) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is var args, you can pass many parameters to function, quando function receive this is convert it to array. Obs: the var args is the last parameter.
For the implementation of String.format() you can see the sources files in your sdk in:
java/sdk.../src.zip

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible: `String.format` itself is in no way a magic method, so I'd suggest you take a look at its source code. The basic language feature is called *varargs*.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String format(String str, Object... args)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String format(String arg1, Object... args)
```

Notice the dots `…` in above code. That mark the last argument of the method as variable argument. You can pass variable amount of parameters using varargs. the vararg must be the last argument in the method.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `Object... args` resulting in an array of arguments, you might want to look into overloading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html